# Git clone private repo and push it like public using another git account

Tags: git, github

I have a doubt the security of private repository protection.

How is the scenario:

A. I have access to the company’s private repository and I can clone the repository to my private laptop. I can work with repo without problem, then I have the necessary access to work.

B. I have another git account, my account. With this account, I can create a new repository and take a git push from the company private repo, that I have been cloned to my private laptop before and now it becomes a public repository, on my account.

My question is:
How I can prevent this action because it is a security issue. After all, the company’s code is part of its business rules of them. Is there any possibility to prevent this?

Comment: What is a "git account"? Git doesn't have accounts. Do you mean a "GitHub account"?

Comment: I don't think there is a technical solution to this. Your local clone is a separate repository, completely under your control and not your company. They have trusted you with access to it; you need to make sure you don't share any part of it on your personal GitHub account.

Comment: Think, though, how you would "accidentally" add your personal public repository as a remote of your company project's repository in the first place. Any leak would seem more like a deliberate action than an accident to protect against.

Comment: This is not an issue related to  git. Employees could also download company documents and upload them to Dropbox or any other platform. If this is a concern, the company should think about hosting services like Github Enterprise, Gitlab etc. internally, limit access to the corporate network to company managed devices only, strictly control the allowed internet traffic, restrict usage of USB devices etc. It is quite an effort, but I know  companies (financial institutions) which need to do this effort in order to prevent data leakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget everything about `git` and code for a moment.

What prevents a user with access from private material from republishing it anywhere at all?  Answer: nothing.  If a user can download the material, republishing it in a public forum is trivial.  The [Digitial Rights Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) (DRM) effort has been trying to stop pirating of copyright protected material with various levels of success for decades.

So, returning to code and `git`, regardless of whether its github/gitlab/gitea/etc, there is nothing that can be done to protect against code leaks.  A company must trust their employees with access that they will not publicly publish code or any other material.  This is often further re-enforced with legal agreements between the employer and the employee.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wes. Your explanation was very clear and direct.